# Try to build auth with Symfony 4 / Apli Platform Token not found 401

Tags: rest, api, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I wanna make a REST API with [API PLATFORM](https://api-platform.com/) and Symfony 4.2
I'm just trying to make the user auth but it fail every times.

I'll will give you each step so may You see where/why I fail:

Create Symfony projet and require all needed :

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton stackoverflow
cd ./stackoverflow
composer req api server maker
```

Then I create user and it's create the security provider etc automatically :

```
php bin/console make:user
```

Then I follow [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](http://LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) install instructions :

```
composer req "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle"
/**
* config/bundles.php
*/
return [
  Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\ApiPlatformBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
  Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
mkdir -p config/jwt
openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096 // pw: stackoverflow
openssl rsa -pubout -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem // pw : stackoverflow
/**
* config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
*/
lexik_jwt_authentication:
 secret_key:  '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
 public_key:  '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
 pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
 token_ttl:   3600
/**
* config/packages/security.yaml
*/
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: argon2i

providers:
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I start server :

```
php bin/console server:run
```

And I try the test from the documentation:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
>   http://localhost/api/login_check -d
>   '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'
>
> If it works, you will receive something like this:
>
> {    "token" :
>   "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MzQ3Mjc1MzYsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoia29ybGVvbiIsImlhdCI6IjE0MzQ2NDExMzYifQ.nh0L_wuJy6ZKIQWh6OrW5hdLkviTs1_bau2GqYdDCB0Yqy_RplkFghsuqMpsFls8zKEErdX5TYCOR7muX0aQvQxGQ4mpBkvMDhJ4-pE4ct2obeMTr_s4X8nC00rBYPofrOONUOR4utbzvbd4d2xT_tj4TdR_0tsr91Y7VskCRFnoXAnNT-qQb7ci7HIBTbutb9zVStOFejrb4aLbr7Fl4byeIEYgp2Gd7gY"
>   }

I must add localhost:8000 of course and I get a very big error, it look like a 1000 lines js script source.

So I skip and try to add the authorize button to swagger :

```
/**
* config/packages/api_platform.yaml
*/
api_platform:
mapping:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
swagger:
     api_keys:
         apiKey:    
            name: Authorization
            type: header
```

And when I gonna localhost:8000 I see :

```
code    401
message "JWT Token not found"
```

I also try all this answer : https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/451#issuecomment-443216804

I found this if it can help either: *var\cache\dev\ContainerT2hNySI\getSecurity_Authentication_Listener_Json_LoginService.php*

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException;
// This file has been auto-generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component for internal use.
// Returns the private 'security.authentication.listener.json.login' shared service.

include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/ListenerInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordJsonAuthenticationListener.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Authentication/CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Authentication/CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Session/SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface.php';

include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/security-http/Session/SessionAuthenticationStrategy.php';

$a = ($this->services['event_dispatcher'] ?? $this->getEventDispatcherService());

$this->privates['security.authentication.listener.json.login'] = $instance = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordJsonAuthenticationListener(($this->services['security.token_storage'] ?? ($this->services['security.token_storage'] = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage())), ($this->privates['security.authentication.manager'] ?? $this->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService()), ($this->privates['security.http_utils'] ?? $this->load('getSecurity_HttpUtilsService.php')), 'login', new \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new \Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler(($this->services['lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager'] ?? $this->load('getLexikJwtAuthentication_JwtManagerService.php')), $a), array(), 'login'), new \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler(new \Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandler($a), array()), array('check_path' => '/api/login_check', 'use_forward' => false, 'require_previous_session' => false, 'username_path' => 'username', 'password_path' => 'password'), ($this->privates['logger'] ?? ($this->privates['logger'] = new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\Logger())), $a, ($this->privates['property_accessor'] ?? $this->getPropertyAccessorService()));

$instance->setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Session\SessionAuthenticationStrategy('none'));

return $instance;
```

My localhost:8000/api headers:

> Cache-Control: no-cache, private Connection: close Content-Type:
>   application/json Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 21:51:51 +0100, Thu, 24 Jan
>   2019 20:51:51 GMT Host: localhost:8000 Link:
>   http://localhost:8000/api/docs.jsonld;
>   rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
>   WWW-Authenticate: Bearer X-Powered-By:
>   PHP/7.2.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language:
>   fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   Connection: keep-alive DNT: 1 Host: localhost:8000
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
>   Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0

The problem may be I cannot do 2nd / 3rd PARTS Obtain the token & Use the token, I don't know if it does matter. (I'm thinking, it's the name of the error "token not found") so all of that for this FFS).

The error I get when I try to obtain the token is like a 1000 lines JS script source, I cannot tell more (I guess it's not allowed to paste as long).

Need some help, thanks.

Comment: do you have users with passwords in your database?

Comment: also check this Github issue: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/346

Comment: Add this - 

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

in your virtual host inside <VirtualHost *:443> and not inside <Directory> . check out this answer: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/346#issuecomment-429081586

Comment: In the readme of branch chapter7-api of [my tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform) i documented all steps i went through to add JWT authentication. The resulting code is in branch chapter8-api, maybe it will help if you can find some difference with what you did.